# Field type for SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST?

Tags: java, sql, spring, package, spring-batch

Need help regarding the stored procedure and spring batch configuration.

```
PROCEDURE MY_DATA(
  MY_DATA_1 IN VARCHAR2,      
  MY_DATA_2 IN NUMBER,
  MY_DATA_3 IN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST);
```

In my XML

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
     <constructor-arg index="0" value="MY_DATA_1"/>
     <constructor-arg index="1">
         <util:constant static-field="java.sql.Types.VARCHAR"/>
     </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
     <constructor-arg index="0" value="MY_DATA_2"/>
     <constructor-arg index="1">
          <util:constant static-field="java.sql.Types.NUMERIC"/>
     </constructor-arg>
</bean>  

<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter">
     <constructor-arg index="0" value="MY_DATA_2"/>
     <constructor-arg index="1">
           <util:constant static-field="**--**"/>
     </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

What is the **static-field** type name we have to provide for SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST ?  I have tried giving java.sql.Types.VARCHAR, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR2 but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle:

```
SQL> desc sys.odcivarchar2list
 Name             Null Type                      
 ---------------- ---- ------------------------- 
 ODCIVARCHAR2LIST      VARYING ARRAY OF VARCHAR2
```

So I would try `java.sql.Types.ARRAY`. If that doesn't work, try the Oracle-specific [example here](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/22034), which leverages Oracle's `ArrayDescriptor` class.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason you are tied to `ODCIVARCHAR2LIST`? If it were up to me, I would just refactor the stored procedure to use standard datatypes.